# How to read SpatialGridDataFrame object into ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a map using ggplot2. Unfortunately, my aes-values, which I want to fill is a gradient of prediction which is in **SpatialGridDataFrame**.

My script is as follows:

```r
ama <- read.csv('Pr.csv')

#rainfall
ama %>% as.data.frame %>% ggplot(aes(LON, LAT)) +
geom_point(aes(size= rainfall), color="blue", alpha=3/4) + 
  ggtitle("RF") + coord_equal() + theme_bw()
coordinates(ama) <- ~ LON + LAT
proj4string(ama) <- ('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs')

#fitting variogram
Annual.vgm <- variogram(log(rainfall) ~ LON + LAT, ama, width=0.1)
Annual.fit = fit.variogram(Annual.vgm, vgm(c("Gau", "Sph", "Mat", "Exp")), fit.kappa = FALSE)
plot(Annual.vgm, Annual.fit)

#newGride creation
names(grd)       <- c("LON", "LAT")
coordinates(grd) <- c("LON", "LAT")
gridded(grd)     <- TRUE  # Create SpatialPixel object
fullgrid(grd)    <- TRUE
crs(grd)= crs('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs')

#kriging interpolation
pred <- krige(rainfall~1, ama, grd, Annual.fit)

#plot the prediction
plot(pred["var1.pred"], crs=TRUE)

#study area map
mystudyarea <- read_sf('mystudyarea.shp')

# ploting using ggplot
ggplot() +
 geom_sf(data=mystudyarea) + geom_sf(pred, 
mapping=aes(fill=pred$var1.pred))+
coord_sf(datum = st_crs(mystudyarea))
```

When I try I get an error - Error in `fortify()`:! `data` must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by  `fortify()`, not an S4 object with class

Comment: Could you provide str(mydata)?

Comment: to elaborate, thanks, mydata is a shapefile for the study area, over which I am interpolating my results from SpatialGrideFrameData (pred$var1.pred). I read mydata by read_sf (mydata) and ploting it on ggplot is not a problem

Comment: Your approach might not yield the desired results. The basic prerequisite for a successful query here is to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This implies that when someone copies and runs your code, they should be able to replicate the issue. Crafting such an example might require some effort on your part. However, the time you invest in creating a minimal reproducible example not only offers you deeper insights and a valuable learning experience but also gives us satisfaction in assisting you effectively. :-)

Comment: I edited the full script except adding the data, which is too long to add here! Everything worked well except the final ggploting part (the problem is from the S4 data (SpatialGridDataFrame)

Comment: The error you're encountering indicates that ggplot cannot read the SpatialGridDataFrame object because it requires a data frame or an sf (simple feature) object. There seems to be a misunderstanding regarding the st_as_sf() function. It is indeed the correct function to convert spatial data to an sf object, which can then be used with ggplot2. You can convert your pred object to an sf object using st_as_sf(pred). Try this approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious information, it worked! Now I am struggling with spplotting and in case you can help on spplot, which I posted today?